# Set today's date as default date when page load in jQuery UI datepicker

Tags: jquery, angularjs, datepicker

I am trying to display today's date as default value in the text box. I have tried below code. It is not working

```html
Start Date : <input tgdatepicker ng-model="searchModel.startTime" id ="startTime" />
End Date   : <input tgdatepicker ng-model="searchModel.endTime" id ="endTime" />
```

```js
$("#startTime").datepicker({ 
    dateFormat: "mm-dd-yy"
}).datepicker("setDate", new Date());
```

Comment: Assuming this is the jQueryUI datepicker, it will start on todays date by default. What is the problem you have with it?

Comment: Above code is working in fiddle. But it is not working in my code. I don't know what is causing issue.

Comment: Check the console (press F12 in your browser) for errors.

Comment: There is no error in the console

Comment: Can I call _updateDatepicker  function  in the textbox.

Comment: You shouldn't need to. Have you put your code in a document ready handler, eg `$(function() { /* your code here... */ });`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83174/discussion-between-n123-and-rory-mccrossan).

Answer (score 0):

You can set default date using : **defaultDate: new Date(1985, 00, 01)**

```
$("#startTime").datepicker({ 
    dateFormat: "mm-dd-yy",
    defaultDate: new Date(2015, 07, 01)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set default date as todays date for jquery date picker using below code:

```
$("#startTime").datepicker().datepicker("setDate", new Date());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var d = new Date();
var year = d.getFullYear();
var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
if (month < 10) {
    month = "0" + month;
};
var day = d.getDate();
$scope.date = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker('setDate', 'today');
```